# Obtain transfer function of op amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, frequency-response

I'm trying to find the transference function H(s) of the next op-amp circuit:

[image]

I get the next following equations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I put the equations together, this is an absurd. How do I solve this?

Comment: What is absurd ? Algebra ?

Comment: Where's the input signal? If it's at the V+ terminal then your V+ equation is wrong.

Comment: Yes - the circuit (with the shown input node) makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is a late answer but I'll give it a shot in case someone else needs it.

The issue in this configuration, if you analyze the circuit, is that you are essentially *forgoing* the positive feedback path. The reason is that by fixing your input signal to the \$V^+\$ input, the positive feedback path (the one with \$C\$ and \$R_2\$) does not have a say in what you are inputting into \$V^+\$.

Feedback networks, as their name indicates, feed a fraction of the output to the input, but in this circuit configuration, there is a constant source established. To better illustrate what I am saying, here is what's happening at \$V^+\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc2HCo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, the voltage going into \$V^+\$ is \$V_{in}\$, which doesn't depend on the feedback network. But even without thinking too much about what I just explained, you can start your analysis with:

$$ V_{out}=A(V^+-V^-)$$
When there are positive and negative feedback networks all in the same OPAmp circuit, it's not always safe to assume that \$V^+=V^-\$ since that only applies when the net feedback is negative. Anyways, here is the analysis:
$$ V^+=V_{in}$$
$$ V^-=\frac{R_3}{R_3+R_4}V_{out}$$

Now plugging this into the first equation:

$$ V_{out}=A\bigg(V_{in}-\frac{R_3}{R_3+R_4}V_{out}\bigg)$$

After some algebra you can obtain your transfer function:

$$ \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=\frac{R_3+R_4}{R_3+\frac{R_3+R_4}{A}}$$

Recall that \$A\$ is really large so that your transfer function now becomes:

$$  \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\approx\frac{R_3+R_4}{R_3}$$

As you can see, it is independent of the positive feedback path (no \$R_2,C,or R_1\$).

To further demonstrate, here is a simulation I built in LTSpice

[image]

As you can see I have \$R_3=1k\Omega\$ and \$R_4=10k\Omega\$ so the voltage gain, \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$, should be around 11. Here is the output voltage now for sine input of with 1V of amplitude:

[image]

The green plot is the output and the blue one is the input.

Now, I have \$R_3=1k\Omega\$ and \$R_4=20k\Omega\$ so the voltage gain, \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$, should be around 21. For the same input (1V sine wave), here is the output:

[image]

You can play around with different values for the positive feedback network (\$R_2\$,\$C\$,or \$R_1\$) and you will find that this, ideally, has no effect on the gain of the circuit. I hope this helps!